# image disappearing when using a Lightbox

Tags: featherlight.js

I have this embedded code on my website:

As I have added to the page now there is a section of the bottom of the page that the image I add in preview mode disappears once the code is active.  I also can not keep images further down if I wanted to add more.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.